# I am new to r. I am trying to make my code less complicated by using a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Here is my current code... can I make this a for loop?

```
#sample1, sample2, …, sample6 where samplei is sampling 10^(ith)
sample1 <- abs(rnorm(10)) #use abs because bellcurve is + and -
sample2 <- abs(rnorm(10^2))
sample3 <- abs(rnorm(10^3))
  sample <- abs(rnorm(10^4))
  sample5 <- abs(rnorm(10^5))
  sample6 <- abs(rnorm(10^6))
```

Comment: `sapply(1:6, function(x)abs(rnorm(10^x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also want to assign it to 6 different variables you will need to do:

```
n = 6
invisible(sapply(1:n, function(i) assign(x = paste("sample", i, sep = ""), 
                                         value = abs(rnorm(10^i)),
                                         envir = .GlobalEnv)))
```

Or with a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:n)
{
  assign(x = paste("sample", i, sep = ""), value = abs(rnorm(10^i)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

But it makes much more sense to store it as a list, like in:

```
samples = lapply(1:6, function(i) abs(rnorm(10^i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

R is really good at vectorization, which means that almost any time you're trying to use a for loop, there's a better/faster way to do it.  I would rewrite your sample as:

```
samples <- abs(rnorm(10^seq(6)))
```

Then each sample can be accessed as `samples[1]` etc.

Comment: This is incorrect. if n is a vector, then the length of the vector is used  ie rnorm(1:3) is the same as rnorm(3).